# Eloquent Model relationship does not return sub-relationship specific column value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have attempted to achieve to pull the user's info and the product details (Which specified the nickname and name) when the product name equal to "Oops" but I have no idea why the getProducts does not return any things.

User Model

```
 public function getProducts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','users_id');
    }
```

Product Model

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

The code of pulling data:

```
$products = User::with(['getProducts' => function($query){
            $query->select("users_id","name","nickname");
        }])->get();
```

The current output:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Smith",
      "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "role": 0,
      "get_products": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Kelvin Ooi",
      "email": "kelvin.ooi@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-04-13T12:07:11.000000Z",
      "role": 1,
      "get_products": [
            {
                "nickname":"MCD",
                "name":"Oops"
            },
            {
                "nickname":"Mary Brown",
                "name":"Oops"
            },
            {
                "nickname":"Kentucy",
                "name":"KFC"
            },
            {
                "nickname":"Texas Chicken",
                "name":"TXS"
            }            
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The expected output

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Smith",
      "email": "john.smith@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "role": 0,
      "get_products": [
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Kelvin Ooi",
      "email": "kelvin.ooi@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:29:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-04-13T12:07:11.000000Z",
      "role": 1,
      "get_products": [
            {
                "nickname":"MCD",
                "name":"Oops"
            },
            {
                "nickname":"Mary Brown",
                "name":"Oops"
            }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I think you need to include `user_id` (the foreign key), so `$query->select('user_id', 'name', 'nickname');`, otherwise it doesn't know how to load them.

Comment: I have checked my db already have foreign key relationship but it still not working..

Comment: What if I would like to pull the user that have name of the product called "Oops"
$products = User::with(['getProducts' => function($query){
            $query->select("users_id","name","nickname");
        }])->where("products.name","Oops")->get();

Comment: but it does not work ..

Comment: Yeah, that code won't work, as `with()` doesn't make `products.name` available to query via `where`. You need to use a `join()` for that syntax :) Also, you have a typo `users_id` is not `user_id`. Also also, maybe include `products.id` too: `$query->select('id', 'user_id', 'name', 'nickname');`

Comment: Actually I am kinda confusing, as the laravel 8.0 docs, the Eloquent model seem like don't have the capability to achieve join tables but the Query Builder does the capability.

Query builder:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries
Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections

Comment: You linked `Eloquent Collections`, which is not quite Eloquent. This is: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent. And `Model::join()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: If I am using User::select("email","fullname")->join("products","products.users_id","=","id")->where("products.name","Oops")->get();
Does this consider eloquent or query builder?

Comment: That is Eloquent :) If it starts with a Model, then it's eloquent. Query Builder generally starts with `DB::`

Comment: But if one day, the developer decide to change the table name without changing the model, then, the code can be hard to maintain because we have hard coded the table name inside the join..

Comment: Precicesly, which is why you should use `with()`, `has()` or `whereHas()` if possible, as those will use the Models and Relationships.

Comment: So I just tested your code with my local models/relationships, and it works: `Model::with(['relationship' => function($q){ $q->select('id', 'relation_id', 'column'); }])->find(1);` This returns the Model where ID is 1, and the relationship records with those 3 columns. Your code should work the same...

Comment: if I would like to add a condition to pull the product detail and user info which matched with the condition "products.name equal to Oops". How can I achieve with using the with()

Comment: P/S: I really quite new for laravel eloquent..

Comment: This is my attempt: User::join('products','products.users_id','=','users.id')->where('products.name','Oops')->select("products.name","products.nickname","users.email",DB::raw("users.name as fullname"))->get()

Comment: but it does not return me a nice collection(json format) as my main thread shown

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere :) And that's where `whereHas()` comes in: `User::with(['getProducts' => function($query){ $query->where('name', 'oops')->select('id', 'users_id', 'name', 'nickname'); }])->whereHas('getProducts', function($query) { $query->where('name', 'oops'); })->get();`. In this case, you'd use both `with()` and `whereHas()` to A) Constrain your parent query to only records where that conditional is met and B) load the matching records for each `User`. Sorry, butchered the format, fixed it now :)

Comment: If I would like to only select the specific columns from the user model such as email and name incorporate with the existing query that you provided.
I have attempted $products = User::with(['products' => function($query){ 
            $query->where('name', 'oops')->select('id', 'users_id', 'name', 'nickname'); 
        }])->whereHas('products', function($query) { 
            $query->where('name', 'oops'); 
        })->get(DB::raw("users.name as fullname"),"users.email","products.*");

but it directly return me empty products collection

Comment: My second attempt: $products = User::select(DB::raw("users.name as fullname"),"users.email")->with(['products' => function($query){ 
            $query->where('name', 'oops')->select('id', 'users_id', 'name', 'nickname'); 
        }])->whereHas('products', function($query) { 
            $query->where('name', 'oops'); 
        })->get();

but still not luck to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`getProducts` is not a good name for the relationship, lets simply call it `products`.

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','users_id');
}
```

Your code in the comment doesn't work because you specify the where clause in the main query, not the sub query.

```php
return User::with(['products' => function ($query) { 
    $query->select("users_id","name","nickname"); 
}])
// This got to be in the sub query.
->where("products.name","Oops")
->get();
```

So let's update your code to this:

```php
$productName = 'Oops';

return User::with(['products' => function ($query) use ($productName) { 
    $query->select("users_id","name","nickname", "price")
        ->where("name","LIKE", "%{$productName}%"); 
}])
->get();
```

I have seen your comment to this answer. Let's define a `total` [custom attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the `User` model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['total'];

    public function getTotalAttribute()
    {
        // This is higher order message, if you haven't used it: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages
        return $this->products->sum->price;
    }
}
```

Then the `total` attribute will be part of any user.

Comment: What if I would like to sum the product price and display the product detail as image shown: https://ibb.co/3hpb8Qx
I have attempted to add "->addSelect("DB::raw("SELECT SUM(p.price) FROM products AS p WHERE p.id = products.id")") before the final get() but it still throw me an error.

Comment: @MiracleHades that wont work. The main query doesn't know about the products table. The query inside the with method is a SEPARATE query to the main one. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Aside from that, if I would like to select id,email and name as fullname from the model instance.
I have attempted to use the pluck() before the with() but I have no luck to get it works..

Comment: I met another problem, I don't know why the products collection still following me when I didn't even include the with('products'). The executable code is $ttl = User::find(1)->first();

Comment: It should only return me plain User Collection instead of User mix Product collection...